# e.preventDefault() behaviour when event occurs

Tags: dom-events

I have one question, when we are working on forms and when Event is occur on onSubmit the url will updated with provided information by form, to prevent this we use e.preventDefault. Can some elaborate why the event has default behavior to update the url on event.

Comment: the submit event just gets fired when the form is submitted. The behaviour bound to that event is to make a new HTTP request to a given url specified in the action attribute of the form. The event.preventDefault() is meant to interrupt the event propagation so that you can block the event from happening and do your own logic instead.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, not all events in JS Dom occur "URL change" as you say. It's only for [form submit event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/submit_event).
Every event has it's default behaviour, predefined by the browser.
According to the documentation, The `preventDefault()` method of the Event interface tells the user agent(the browser) that if the event does not get explicitly handled, its default action should not be taken as it normally would be.
More details [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault)!